# Extra Div and Class remove from Top Navigation Snippet

Tags: 2013, navigation, managed-navigation

I can create top navigation snippet by going to master page and clicking snippet. But it prints lots of div and extra classes. That's messing my CSS for the html navigation. Is there any way to print it only

- Home
- About Us

etc. by eliminating all other extra tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, you can't do it. Just create your own control. But I recently did custom design, and I solve this problem.

Create a little js script, that remove all css classes from rendered html, except "ms-hidden" class. You can insert it in masterpage right after the control.

```
clearCss(document.getElementById('DeltaTopNavigation');
function clearCss(element) {
  var childs = element.childNodes;
  for (var i = 0; i < childs.length; i++) {
    if (childs[i].className != 'ms-hidden') {
      childs[i].className = '';
    }
    clearCss(childs[i]);
  }
}
```

Set styles in css like this:

```
#DeltaTopNavigation {}
#DeltaTopNavigation ul {}
#DeltaTopNavigation ul li {}
#DeltaTopNavigation ul li a {}
```

For me it's working great.

Comment: thanks for the solution. Ya Seems like it's not possible without using your own custom way.